# SQL Server Bulk Insert Format FIle could not be opened

Tags: sql-server, format, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use Bulk Insert to insert some data into my database on local computer. I am using a SQL Server Express database and executing query using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When I try to execute a query I get this error.

> Cannot bulk load because the file "‪D:\Countries.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

I have been moving this file over my HDD by everywhere and still got the same error. To be honest I have no idea what is going on. Any tips?

```
BULK INSERT Research.dbo.Countries
FROM 'C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\Localization DB\countryInfo.txt' WITH 
    (
        FORMATFILE='‪D:\Countries.xml',
        FIRSTROW=2,
        CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    );
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you copy a path for example from properties of file

[image: copy path]

copied text have some extra thrash bytes, you need to view pasted text as ANSI and will be revealed

[image: pasted text as utf-8]

[image: pasted text as ansi]

Answer (score 3):

Are you 100% sure you are connecting to you locally installed SQL Server - not a networked one?
That's my favorite thing to do, rdp into a machine, or on a VM, and forget where I am physically connected. If you copy and paste from Word, sometimes it puts in the wrong type of '  back that out and replace.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why but the problem was with ' mark being copied. When i deleted it and put it from keyboard it started working.